# Definir um array e o tipo de uma função em C

Tags: c, array, estrutura-de-dados, struct, funções

Olá,

Estou a desenvolver um projecto de inicialização à linguagem C, nomeadamente, a criação de um Sistema de Gestão Multimédia que terá de ser capaz de gerir uma base de dados de artigos discográficos como CDs, DVDs e Discos de Vinil.

De momento, após ter declarado a estrutura (não sei se está correcta), tenho esta dúvida:

- Como definir um array que possa conter os artigos para depois poder definir o tipo da função **consultaArtigo()** e nesse caso, como definir essa função? Basicamente, eu queria "dizer" à função qual a referência do artigo para que a função me possa procurar esse livro. No fim, a função teria de me devolver o resultado do artigo.

Eis o meu código fonte para já:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// prototipagem de funções:
int menuPrincipal(void);
void consultarArtigo(void);
void removerArtigo(void);
void alterarArtigo(void);
void inserirArtigo(void);

// estruturas:
typedef struct {
    int numero_unico_de_registo;
    char titulo_do_artigo[30];
    char area_discografica; // dizer se é do tipo CD, DVD ou Vinil?
    char nome_do_artista[30];
    int ano_de_lancamento;
    int estante_de_localizacao; // as estantes seriam identificadas por numeros?    
} ARTIGO;

// Função MAIN:
int main()
{
    menuPrincipal();
    return;
}

// Funções AUX:
int menuPrincipal(void){

    int opcao;

    do {

    printf("Bem-Vindo ao MMS!\n");
    printf("1 - Consultar Artigo Discografico\n");
    printf("2 - Remover Artigo Discografico\n");
    printf("3 - Alterar Artigo Discografico!\n");
    printf("4 - Inserir Artigo!\n");
    printf("0 - Fechar!\n");
    printf("Escolha a sua opcao!\n");
    scanf("%d", &opcao);

    switch(opcao) {
        case 1: consultarArtigo();
        break;
        case 2: removerArtigo();
        break;
        case 3: alterarArtigo();
        break;
        case 4: inserirArtigo();
        break;
        case 0: printf("Sair do Menu!");
        default: printf("Opcao invalida, tente de novo.\n");
    }

    } while (opcao != 0);

    return(opcao);
}

void consultarArtigo(void) {
    printf("Entrei na funcao Consultar Artigo!\n");
}

void removerArtigo(void) {
    printf("Entrei na funcao Remover Artigo!\n");
}

void alterarArtigo(void){
    printf("Entrei na funcao Alterar Artigo!\n");
}

void inserirArtigo(void){
    printf("Entrei na funcao Inserir Artigo!\n");
}
```

[Código originalmente colocado no ideone](http://ideone.com/uwxw4o)

Qualquer dica, seria bem-vinda.

Answer (score 2):

**1) Qual o dado?**

A primeira parte é definir uma estrutura que vai armazenar os artigos e todas as informações a respeito dele que você precisar, o que você já fez.

```
// estruturas:
typedef struct {
    int numero_unico_de_registo;
    char titulo_do_artigo[30];
    char area_discografica; // dizer se é do tipo CD, DVD ou Vinil?
    char nome_do_artista[30];
    int ano_de_lancamento;
    int estante_de_localizacao; // as estantes seriam identificadas por numeros?    
} ARTIGO;
```

**2) Qual a estrutura?**

A segunda parte é definir qual a estrutura de dados que você vai utilizar. Se o número de artigos ativos tiver um limite (talvez o número que você imagina como máximo para a sua biblioteca), não tem muito problema você usar um array, mas é possível que você precise alocar indefinidamente memória para colocar os artigos, nesse caso eu recomendo que procure usar uma árvore ou uma lista.

Tem que decidir se vai manter os artigos ordenados pelo numero_unico_de_registro ou não. Pelo que entendi, você vai precisar buscar por qualquer campo, então não parece te ajudar muito ordenar.

Para declarar o array, basta, logo abaixo da definição do ARTIGO, colocar:

```
#define NUMERO_MAXIMO_DE_ARTIGOS 50 //número máximo permitido
struct listaDeArtigos ARTIGO[NUMERO_MAXIMO_DE_ARTIGOS]; //declaração do array
int numeroDeArtigos = 0; //para guardar o numero atual de artigos
```

**3) Implementar as funções**

Aqui vão algumas dicas:

Para fazer a consulta, basta você pedir ao usuário qual o campo que ele quer buscar e o valor do campo. Então você percorre todas as posições até o numeroDeArtigos e retorna o artigo encontrado ou retorna não encontrado.

Ao remover um artigo, mova todos os outros até o final, mantendo sempre o início do seu array preenchido.

Procure sempre inserir um artigo no final se a ordem não fizer diferença.

A função de alterar artigo, é basicamente um progresso da função de consulta, então, faça ela primeiro.